# block double request while ajax is pending

Tags: ajax, jquery

I really need to understand how block the requests ajax while is pending. Let me explain an example:

I have an input type called "share" and when I write something and press enter ajax take the result and it insert inside mysql. If I do this pressing a lot of time the enter button it take more results like how many times I pressed enter even if there is a control in php. I think is a problem of the request ajax because the control php I'm sure is right. Thank you so much.

this is the code of example:

form

```
<input type="text" class="share">
```

Js

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) { // function for check when i press enter
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}

$('.share').enterKey(function() { // ajax request
    var comment = $(this);
    if (comment.val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  add_comment.urlRemove,
            data: "text=" + comment.val(),
            success: function(html) {
                comment.val('');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error on ajax call');
            }
        }); 
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to determine whether or not the request has already been sent, like this:

```
var alreadySent = false;

$('.share').enterKey(function() {
    var comment = $(this);
    if (comment.val() != "") {   
        if(!requestSent) {
            // Set variable to true
            alreadySent = true;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  add_comment.urlRemove,
                data: "text=" + comment.val(),
                success: function(html) {
                    // Set variable to false
                    alreadySent = false;
                    comment.val('');
                },
                error: function(){
                    // Set variable to false
                    alreadySent = false;
                    alert('Error on ajax call');
                }
           }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: He's not using a button click to invoke the AJAX fyi.

Comment: Thank you, i think is perfect, i have some questions about if i can, this method is secure? Can i use this method for all the events? ex, click, hover, ecc... Thank you so much!

Comment: @fabrizio - you can use this method for all events (click, hover), but you will need to have multiple variables to maintain the value of whether each type of event AJAX call has already been sent or not.

Comment: Ok thanks, but you mean that I have to put different name variable for each request ajax right? ps: you forget to answer if is secure sorry. :)